# Inline assembly for 64 bit cmp in x86-64

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly

I am trying to write 64 bit cmp within inline assembly following the last version of CMP at [1]. Currently I have the following.

```
int main() {
  asm("cmpl $0x0011001100110011, %rdi");
}
```

But I get the following error.

`` incorrect register `%rdi' used with `l' suffix ``

What should be the correct format to encode this instruction?

[1] http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMP.html

Comment: Maybe you mean to use `cmpq` and do you mean hex `$0x0011001100110011` or binary `$0b0011001100110011` ?

Comment: If you in fact want to compare a full 64-bit value then you could do `movq $0x0011001100110011, %rax` and then `cmpl %rax, %rdi`

Comment: I meant to use cmpq (my bad) with the hex value. So asm("cmpq $0x0011001100110011, %rdi"); wouldn't work as well apparently.

Comment: If you review the instruction set that you linked to there is no _CMP_ that takes a 64-bit register (r64) and a 64-bit immediate (imm64) value. You either have to _MOV_ to get a 64-bit immediate value (imm64) in a 64-bit register (r64) and then compare that register with _RDI_, or you can use _CMP_ with _RDI_ and a 64-bit value as a memory operand (m64).